# Android Cannot stop rotation animation

Tags: android, animation

I am using this [library](https://github.com/thunderrise/android-TNRAnimationHelper) to animate an `ImageView`. It works very good however, I cannot find the way to stop the animation.
I have tried:

```
image_1.clearAnimation();
image_1.setAnimation(null);
image_1.animate().cancel();
```

Comment: it would be easier to tell us when you wanna stop the animation.

Comment: I need to stop the animation when a button is clicked

Comment: add the code where are u starting the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `AnimationListener`to your animation. It would be easier for you to stop the animation when it's working or maybe after couple of rounds

Comment: The animation will go until I click a button for stopping it

Comment: update your question with more code lines to really see your implementation